# Using "the" and "a" in title, figure titles, and headings in an academic paper

Tags: articles, headlinese, academic-writing

Is it acceptable to drop "a" and "the" words in the title, figure titles, and headings in an academic paper or on a NEWS website?

For example:

Instead of writing:

- "The relationship between the pressure and the temperature of the tank of the system"

We write:

- "Relationship between pressure and temperature of the tank of the system"

Or:

- "the variable of the system"
- "variable of system"

Are there any other governing rules?

Comment: These are not "governing rules".  "The" and "A" may be included if you wish.  But if headlines have to be short, then they are shortened by various means, including by omitting words that can be guessed, and substituting unusual (but short) words.  You should NOT do this in academic papers, where titles can be as long as you like, and where precise meaning is essential.

Comment: Your first example is hopelessly non-idiomatic. Note that (primarily *because it's just a "noun phrase"*), the text as presented can't possibly be anything *except* a "title". Feasibly you might say *John was asked to investigate **the** relationship between system tank pressure and temperature*, where that first highlighted article is effectively *required* - but ***as a title***, it would almost always just start with the word "relationship". You confuse the issue by mixing up "titles" and "sentences".

Comment: I suggest searching for "headlinese", which is the slang term for the style of shortened headlines and titles.

Comment: We would use: the system's variable, and no "of the"

Answer (score 1):

All style issues should consider your intended audience. Always check for an accepted style in the place you intend to publish. There may not be a formal guide, but you can usually check what previous authors have done.

Titles are not required to be complete sentences. Indeed, it is better if they are not. Think of them as sign posts giving information of what is ahead. As such, you should be considering what makes them useful and informative.

Another aspect of titles is considering how they appear in the table of contents (TOC). Long chatty titles tend to bulk up the TOC and make it difficult to use.

Consider your example:

- "The relationship between the pressure and the temperature of the tank of the  system"

You shortened that as follows.

- "Relationship between pressure and temperature of the tank of the system"

This is an improvement. But you could even go farther.

- Tank System Pressure-Temperature Relationship

This has reduced the title to essentially a label indicating the content of the following text.  Depending on specifics you might modify this a bit with some careful punctuation. For example, suppose that you had several sections detailing things related to the tank system. You could highlight this as follows.

- Tank System: General
- Tank System: Components
- Tank System: Alarm Conditions
- Tank System: Pressure-Temperature Relationship
- Tank System: External Interface

This is terse, informative, and looks good in the TOC. It's something you might expect to see in an engineering type publication, which I infer from "tank system." But recall the style advice from the begining. Some audiences will not like such a style.

Comment: I basically agree with you but think the word relationship can be dropped: "Pressure and temperature in the tank system"

Comment: @Lambie Possibly. It depends if the document is specifically talking about the relationship. For example, it might be a formula or a table-of-values or some such. So it might need to be there. It's a question of emphasis.